# What is the best hardware wallet for Monero?

Tags: trezor, development-roadmap, hardware-wallet, ledger

It appears there is some work being done to support Monero on Trezor 2.0:

https://twitter.com/fluffyponyza/status/814143827384631296
and
https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/5d24ej/update_on_the_monero_trezor_firmware/

Is there any update on this?  Are there any other hardware wallets that support Monero?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently, there are not any hardware wallets with Monero compatibility. Ledger and Trezor have both expressed interest in adding Monero support but nothing is forthcoming, at least that is public knowledge.

Answer (score 8):

Ledger say Monero is on their roadmap in their FAQ http://support.ledgerwallet.com/knowledge_base/topics/general-ledger-nano-s-faq

Comment: That link now redirects to a portal. Searching the site for monero gives no results. [Tried the Way Back Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20161128124711/http://support.ledgerwallet.com/knowledge_base/topics/general-ledger-nano-s-faq) but not to much luck.

Answer (score 4):

A bit late to the party, but here is the Monero entry in Ledger's roadmap: https://trello.com/c/wsK0myEm/52-monero-support

Apparently (if you follow the last reddit link) a first alpha release is planned for September.
No info regarding a stable release yet though.

Answer (score -2):

Here is an existing community-run example for a hardware wallet. Definitely promising!
https://forum.getmonero.org/7/open-tasks/88149/dedicated-monero-hardware-wallet

Comment: Welcome to Monero! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.